# Lua library/wrapper for cryptography

Tags: cryptography, lua, sha1

I'm looking for a library or wrapper for Lua to use some cryptographic functions. Initially I only need to create SHA-1 hashs.

Any tips or suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lmd5

Comment: i installed this one, but i can`t find any documentation to begin. So, i have it, but don`t know how to use it.

Comment: Some very basic instructions are inside the .tar.gz:
    digest library:
     __tostring(c)    new()     version 
     clone(c)    reset(c) 
     digest(c or s,[raw])   update(c,s) 
There is also a test.lua in the archive that shows you the library in action...

Comment: If you have any questions, post here or contact me directly.

Comment: but it doesnt work with SHA-1. At least i didnt found it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If your needs are simple, take a look at [Lua/APR](http://peterodding.com/code/lua/apr) - Lua bindings for the Apache Portable Runtime.  It provides routines for MD5 and SHA-1.  Works with strings or files.

Lots of other useful stuff in Lua/APR too.

Answer (score 1):

or [luacrypto](http://luacrypto.luaforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do some encryption/decryption or public key cryptography later, you can take a look at my fork of luacrypto at http://github.com/mkottman/luacrypto , which is a binding to OpenSSL, and provides hashing, HMAC, symetric cryptograhy and asymetric signing/verifying.

The API is relatively simple, the reference is located here: http://mkottman.github.com/luacrypto/manual.html